# Is using of “each” along with “apiece” redundant in this sentence?

Tags: redundancy

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in an article titled “[Kooky Politics Make for Entertaining Races](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/06/21/us/21iht-letter.html)" by Albert R. Hunt in The New York Times (June 20, 2010).

> The figure seemed odd until it was disclosed that of Mr. Ensign’s
>   parents each gave $12,000 apiece to the four members of the aide’s
>   family, the maximum allowed without having to file a gift tax return
>   with the Internal Revenue Service.

Can someone clarify if the word "apiece" is unnecessary, as I think it is?

I would drop "apiece", but I'm not sure on this correction because constructions like "each ... $[X] ... apiece" occurs on many occasions on The New York Times and it frequently occurs in others newspapers. So I am wondering if it is in common usage, albeit it isn't the highest register.

Comment: No, it's not. Each of Mr. Ensign's parents gave $12,000 to each of the four members of the aide's family, eight transactions total. The "each" applies to Mr. Ensign's two parents; the "apiece" to the four members of the aide's family. It is undoubtedly a confusing way to have worded it, but it's not redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Both words (*[each](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/each)* and *[apiece](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apiece)*) are  needed here, as the intended meaning is that each parent gave $12000 to each aide’s family member.  However, the sentence as published (which is as shown in question) is jumbled compared to what one normally sees; the *each* is differently placed, as noted below.  The sentence could read,

> ...it was disclosed that each of Mr. Ensign’s parents gave $12,000 apiece to the four members of the aide’s family...

The published sentence's structure is "...that of *X* each gave...", which means "...considering *X*, each of *X* gave...", which is equivalent to "...each of *X* gave...".  The author's intent may have been to have *each* and *apiece* close together to account for the arithmetic of getting $96000 from $12000:  two parents times four recipients times $12000.

Answer (score 3):

Arguably it's clumsy phrasing, but it's certainly not redundant.

The word **each** refers to *each of Mr. Ensign's parents*, but **apiece** refers to *the four members of the aide’s family*.

If *each* were to be dropped, we might reasonably assume that collectively the parents gave a total of $12,000, where in fact there was one such donation from his mother, and one from his father.

If *apiece* were to be dropped, we'd assume the donation (or, *both* donations) of $12,000 was shared between the four recipients ($3,000 or $6,000 each). In fact they each got $24,000 ($12,000 from each parent). Which was the most they could get without the tax authorities becoming involved.